# How to map some property to private property using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

How to map public property `Source.Name` to **private** property `Destination.Name` using Automapper.

```
public class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Destination
{
    private string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoMapper mapping properties with private setters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355024/automapper-mapping-properties-with-private-setters)

Comment: It is not duplicate since the whole property is private not only setter. Mapping property with private setter is fine but if the whole property is private I receive an exception.

Comment: Did you read *all* answers?

Comment: Yes I do. None of them solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
          {
            cfg.ShouldMapProperty = pi => pi.PropertyType.IsPublic || pi.PropertyType.IsNotPublic;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates fake lambda expression. In this example it creates `(Destination) => Destination.Name` lambda.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(CreateMemberLambda<Destination>("Name"), mo => mo.MapFrom(sm => sm.Name));

var source = new Source() { Name = "foo" };
var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
```

---

```
public Expression<Func<T, object>> CreateMemberLambda<T>(string parameterName)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    var parameter = type.GetProperty(parameterName, bindFlags);
    var classExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, type.Name);
    var memberAccessExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(classExpression, parameter);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(memberAccessExpression, classExpression);

    return lambda;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is quite old but I've found out with the same problem and modifying a little the CreateMemberLambda method that MaciejLisCK exposes worked for me.

```
public Expression<Func<T, object>> CreateMemberLambda<T>(string parameterName)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField;

        var parameter = type.GetField(parameterName, bindFlags);
        var classExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, type.Name);
        var memberAccessExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(classExpression, parameter);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(memberAccessExpression, classExpression);

        return lambda;
    }
```