# How to use AutoMapper to map to a class with readonly only properties?

Tags: c#, automapper, readonly

First up this is not a duplicate of [AutoMapper mapping properties with private setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355024/automapper-mapping-properties-with-private-setters) , because that deals with 'properties with private setters' **not** readonly setters. Although I would be happy to merge, if needed.

```cs
public class Example{

 public string PrivateSetter { get; private set;}
 public string ReadonlyProperty { get; }

}
```

Now that *nullable reference types* is a thing. I want to create dtos/models that follow that practice. however if I have a class with a property of say `public string Name { get; set; }` I get warnings that `Name` may be null. So I thought I would change the property to be a readonly property `public string Name { get; }` which I initialize in the constructor. Sweet! That made my null warning go away. But boom now at runtime my auto mapper dies. It cant find a parameterless constructor.

Now one way around this is to setup my mapper like this:

```cs
public class SourceClass
{
  public string Name { get; }
}

public class DestinationClass
{

  public DestinationClass(string name)
  { 
    Name = name; 
  }

  public string Name { get; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
            .ConstructUsing(s => new DestinationClass(s.Name));
```

However that is pretty rubbish! As I now need to manually map every property, in the correct order, in the `.ConstructUsing()` method. Which kinda defeats the point of using *Automapper*.

So my question is **How can I map to a class, with read only properties, using *Automapper*; without having to use .ConstructUsing()` and manually map every property into the constructor?**

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Comment: Just add the readonly properties to the DestinationClass contructor, the other properties will be mapped automatically..(That's how ConstructUsing works)

Comment: @JamalSalman Can you do that without having to specify each constructor parameter?