# Automapper: Trying to map to a property with a private setter

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map to a class that contains a property with a private setter. I read in a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355024/automapper-mapping-properties-with-private-setters) that this was possible (Automapper apparently used Reflection to do so) just as long as I configured the property in question with the ForMember method (see below)

**Mapper config**

```
      var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<IDbCoverage, ICoverage>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CoverageCodeDesc, conf => conf.MapFrom(src => src.CoverageCodeDesc)); 
        });
```

**Interfaces**

```
public interface IDbCoverage
{
    string ExternalMemberId { get; set; }
    string CoverageCode { get; set; }
    string CoverageCodeDesc { get; }
}


public interface ICoverage
{
    string ExternalMemberId { get; set; }       
    string CoverageCode { get; set; }
    string CoverageCodeDesc { get; }
}
```

**Instantiation of the destination class:**

```
public class Coverage 
{
    public string ExternalMemberId { get; set; }
    public string CoverageCode { get; set; } 
    public string CoverageCodeDesc { get; private set; }
}
```

However when I try this only the properties with public setters are mapped. The source value of the other property is not mapped and the destination class ends up with a null value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried the latest and it just works, you don't need the `MapFrom`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu can you explain that a bit more please? If I remove the MapFrom it does not compile. If I remove the entire ForMember method it does not map the property.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu [here you go](https://gist.github.com/Sperick/9ecb3226ea46abda4cafeb3971c6cfcf)

Comment: The interface has no setter. There is no connection between that class and the mapping. Drop the interfaces and create the map for the classes and the problem is solved.